# Always open as root?

Tags: debian, root, file-browser

I have to right-click in my File Browser to open as root (more specifically, any time I want to edit files), and I'd like to prevent having to do this step every time. I edit files a lot, obviously

- Coming from Windows!

Comment: Login as root..

Comment: Use the terminal to become root and then edit the files that way. It's a lot more efficient than using the file browser.

Comment: I have no idea which DE you are using, but just run the file-browser as root, e.g. `sudo dolphin`. I don't recommend it though, for security concerns.

Comment: Naughty naughty.  Learn how to use a text editor - vi/vim (painful but very powerful if you can get through learning it well enough), nano (small, simple, and always there) are in all *nix systems, I like `joe` because it is a clone of the wordprocessor i used back in the 80s, plenty of others.  GUI is great for desktop use and managing files in a desktop environment, but for system administration the command line and text editor is "better"  - for me anyway.

Comment: I wonder what you have to edit that much as root; I rarely, if ever, do that and then I'm usually doing it comfortably from a root (unrestricted) shell, instead of switching ids back and forth. Anyways, running a "File Browser" or full desktop environment as root is a lousy advice -- you may be the best rootest guy in the universe, those gnome/kde/whatever beasts are usually so broken that you'll end up hosing your system even without being exploited or doing any mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can run at the most local level *something* as root. For example,

- If you need to run all command in terminal as root, simply get root in a terminal `sudo su`.
- If you need to run all commands in file browser as root, simply get root in a file browser by running `gksudo nautilus` (or whatever file browser you're using)

Note. This isn't very wise. You don't normally want to edit `ANY` files as root. If you're editing them all the time, consider stepping back and asking a better question with more of your workflow -- like "how would you do this."

It's also very normal for these questions to emerge because **something is running as root that shouldn't be running as root** then that something creates its files as root. If this is the case, consider running whatever is creating the files as your local user. Or, as a user in the same group.

Comment: What benefit does `sudo su` have over `sudo -s`?

Comment: That's a different question, and we discourage that on the site. But to not be a jerk about it `sudo su` does not preserve the environment while `sudo -s` does, and if that doesn't mean anything to you'll have to ask another question.

Comment: Who wouldn't prefer their own environment?  Or... sudo -i...

Comment: ... new question.

Comment: EvanCarroll, I think @EdGrimm is not so much asking a new question per se, but querying the validity of your suggestions. I also use `sudo -i`. Similarly, AFAIK `gksudo` has been deprecated, and removed from many distros. I *think* (but am not sure) that plain `sudo` should work now, possibly with `-H` depending on your distro's defaults.